# Elastic search was not working in Magento 2.3.2 (Enterprise edition)

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.1, magento2.3.2, elasticsearch

Here I have configured the **elastic search 6.0 in Magento 2.3.2** (Enterprise Edition).
Backend configurations are done and it shows Successfully connected.

FYR, I have attached the screenshot for backend configuration,

[image]

After configuring **Elastic search 6.0** configurations, I did the following steps,

1. In Admin panel refresh the Page cache in Cache Management
2. Clean the cache in server.
3. After that run the following command in the server

   `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

But in frontend normal search only working.

Is there any method to check the Elastic search is working or not?

How can we know it's working properly? Suggest me some ideas if anything is missed.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: I believe that you have some customization that break it...

Answer (score 6):

Open below URL directly in the browser

```
http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices?v
```

> **127.0.0.1** - Replace with Elasticsearch Server Hostname
>
> **9200**  - Replace with Elasticsearch Server Port

Will show below table:

```
health status index              uuid                       pri rep     docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   magento2_product_1_v1 36z4LMghSvSMLV2_9itYSg   5   1         50            0       89kb           89kb
yellow open   magento2_product_2_v1 dxUmodV_S0i_Y5Tcv10zIQ   5   1         52            0     86.3kb         86.3kb
```

In the above table, it will list out all the indexes and along with the `docs.count`, that will show how many documents(products) are already indexed.
`docs.deleted` column will show if any document which may require indexing. It will be reset to 0 once reindexing performed from Magento.

To show which products have been indexed as documents in the elastic search.

```
http://127.0.0.1:9200/magento2_product_2_v1/_search?pretty=true
```

> **magento2_product_2_v1**  = If require then replace index name

Will show something as below along with all product information.

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 52,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "magento2_product_2_v1",
        "_type" : "document",
        "_id" : "14",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "store_id" : "2",
          "sku" : "SKU-6KYPBY3CMK",
          "status" : "1",
          "status_value" : "Enabled",.....
```

`"total"` will show how many products exist in the index. Here it is 52.

Use below commands to verify explicitly whether elastic search returning results or not.

Will show results name having bag

```
curl -X GET "127.0.0.1:9200/magento2_product_2_v1/_search?q=name:bag&pretty"
```

Will show results name having * :)

```
curl -X GET "127.0.0.1:9200/magento2_product_2_v1/_search?q=name:*&pretty"
```

Will show all the products of a given index

```
curl -X GET "127.0.0.1:9200/magento2_product_2_v1/_search?q=*:*&pretty"
```

Search across all available indices using below

```
curl -X GET "127.0.0.1:9200/_all/_search?q=*:*&pretty"
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed notes sandip. But it's not working for me.

Comment: Sharing the logs of system exceptions, support_report can identify the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Following [this page](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-overview.html) Have you tried running -

> Verify that Elasticsearch is working by entering the following command on the server on which it is running:

```
curl -XGET '<host>:9200/_cat/health?v&pretty'
```

> A message similar to the following is displayed:

```
 epoch      timestamp cluster       status node.total node.data shards pri relo init unassign pending_tasks
 1519701563 03:19:23  elasticsearch green           1         1      0   0    0    0        0             0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply BigDaddyL, Here I have attached my result here

`epoch      timestamp cluster        status node.total node.data shards pri relo init unassign pending_tasks max_task_wait_time active_shards_percent
1565614439 12:53:59  docker-cluster yellow          1         1      5   5    0    0        5             0                  -                 50.0%`

Comment: How can i justify the elastic search is working or not.

Comment: For me, the status shows "Yellow", is that means working or not?

Comment: @Jack _yellow means that the primary shard is allocated but replicas are not_ ... found at [Cluster Health API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html#cluster-health-api-desc)

Answer (score 2):

You can try monitoring the elasticsearch slowlog to see how the queries are actually being executed. Change the index from twitter to whatever your index name is or * for all. Then you can find the logs at:

var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_index_search_slowlog.log

```
PUT /twitter/_settings {
     "index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.debug": "0s",
     "index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.debug": "0s",
     "index.search.slowlog.level": "debug" 
}
```

Here is a link to the elastic search (6.8) documentation on how to do this.

[Elastic Search 6.8 Slowlog](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/index-modules-slowlog.html)