# Add Elastic Search on magento 2.2 without composer

Tags: magento2

i have Mangento 2.2 site on which i want to add elastic search. According to the documentation we can add the same using composer, but my problem is i cannot use composer. Is there any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: I'm also facing same issue

Comment: Magneto 2 comes with elasticsearch out of the box. as long as your server is setup for elasticsearch then you should just be able to set it up

Comment: No, @DavaGordon
It started after 2.2, its not included in 2.2. I checked with server support also. Its not coming by default in magento 2.2

Comment: To manually download you can go to https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/tree/2.2.x and download it if you want to install in the app folder you will need to do a bit of work in regards to folder structures of each module

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to execute composer locally on your machine and upload the generated files to your server somewhere in
`<magento-root>\lib` or create a new folder on `<magento-root>` folder.

Steps to implement at local machine. This is for [core elastic search lib](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php).

1. create a `composer.json` on your local machine with following require

`{ "require": { "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "^7.0" } }`

2. run `composer install -vvv`
3. now vendor folder will be there it will load all the dependencies with `autoload.php` file which as code to include all the dependencies.

There will be duplication of dependencies like `Psr\Logger` and it can be removed if its already there in Magento's(on your web server where you intent to deploy) **vendor** folder.

From your local machine only if needed - optional.

4. `composer remove ezimuel/ringphp`
5. `composer remove psr/log`

Internally, composer is

A) downloading all the dependencies and

B) generating an "autoload.php" file which has code to include all the dependencies.

Once everything is generated, the files and directory structure are static and can easily be moved around.

At this stage you will have core elastic search lib package ready in your local machine ready to deploy on your server.

6. In Magento (2.2) project deploy that zip folder to server in `<magento-root>\lib` or custom folder of your choice on `<magento-root>` folder.

**Magento Part**

Now install these two Magento's modules in `app/code/Magento/Elasticsearch` and `Magento/Elasticsearch7`

1. https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.4/app/code/Magento/Elasticsearch
2. https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.4/app/code/Magento/Elasticsearch7

you may have to change some require_once or namespace settings in `Magento/Elasticsearch` and `Magento/Elasticsearch7` modules as per your core elasticsearch lib location.

**Preconditions**

1. Web server should have Elastic search 7 version installed.
2. Some [Elastic Search Requirements](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/installation.html#installation)

[Check elasticsearch installed or not](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/285358/34579)